# Inheriting width from css display: grid column and applying it to a position: fixed child

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-grid

On this example, I would like to expand the div containing ABC to the full width of its container.

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.col {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100vh;
}

.col:nth-child(2) {
  background: #aaa;
}

.bottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div class="col">
    <span>1</span>
    <div class="bottom">ABC</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ojms0rur/

I'm getting this:
[image: Problem Screen Capture]

Where I'd like this:

[image: Solution Sketch]

How would I go about inheriting the width from the parent grid column and applying it to this fixed position element?

Comment: Set the body margins to 0, and use 50% - or keep body margins if you need them, but then specify a value yourself, and use that with calc and 50% ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working this way because you are inheriting from element with `width: auto`.

To make it work how you expect you should set width for grid item explicitly (e. g. `50vw`). In this case you can set `auto` for parent grid column width in `grid-template-columns` value to avoid duplicate CSS. Demo:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.col {
  background: #ccc;
  /* setting width explicitly */
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.col:nth-child(2) {
  background: #aaa;
}

.bottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div class="col">
    <span>1</span>
    <div class="bottom">ABC</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

By the way setting percentage width for grid column won't work because percentage for grid column are relative to grid area and percentage for fixed position elements are relative to screen.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` on the `.bottom` div you can set its parent `.col` to `position: relative` and just use `width: 100%` on `.bottom` as it will now be absolutely positioned relative to its parent.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojms0rur/1/)

Comment: This helped me since I wasn't willing to explicitly specify the width of the grid item.

Comment: The `.bottom` element doesn't take up the space of the 1st column but the entire space up to the right side of the viewport (Edge v115). This can be seen by scrolling to the end of the page. By adding `text-align: center;` to `.bottom`, only the `A` of the text `ABC` is fully visible, the rest is hidden behind the 2nd column.